# Subtract a number from a label

Tags: c#, label, subtraction

I am new to C# and I got a question about how to subtract a number from a label?

I am trying to make an application. The situation is as followed:

I got a button that says "attack" and there is a label called "lblTotalEnemyLifes". Now when I press the button I want to subtract 1 "damage" from the total hp that the label has and the label would automatically be updated after I press the button. I tried alot of different things and nothing seems to work. At the moment I tried things like:

```
int damage = -1;

int life = Convert.ToInt32(lblTotalEnemyLifes.Text);

life = life - damage;
```

I tried alot more then this. If someone could help me how I subtract a number from a label.. that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, subtracting a negative value `-(-1)` will add to life.  Other than that what is broken?

Comment: Mathematically incorrect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are subtracting the  number but don't write it back:

```
lblTotalEnemyLifes.Text = life.ToString();
```

Changing the value of `life` doesn't affect your label.You should update label's `Text` property.

And also you are subtracting `-1` instead of `1` and the expression becomes `life = life + 1`. You can just use the `decrement` operator to substract `1` from your variable:

```
int life = Convert.ToInt32(lblTotalEnemyLifes.Text);
life--; // equivelant to life = life - 1;

lblTotalEnemyLifes.Text = life.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply

Comment: It is true what you said. I didn't wrote it back to my label. Thanks alot!

Comment: @MaximedeLange you should click the checkmark to indicate this fixed your problem.  Especially since it helped with another problem you did not even know you had yet.

Comment: yep. true. first time today I use stackoverflow. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2):

another approach, possible more elegant and less error prone, is this:

wrapp your value in a class:

```
public class GameState
{
    public int TotalEnemyLifes { get; set; }
}
```

next, instantiate the class and bind it to the UI:

```
var ctx = new GameState { TotalEnemyLifes = LIFE_VALUE };
this.DataContext = ctx;
```

next, update the value in your button event handler:

```
private void event_Handler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ctx.TotalEnemyLifes--;
    BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(lblTotalEnemyLifes, Label.ContentProperty).UpdateTarget();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set damage to 1, not -1.
Then add at the end:

lblTotalEnemyLifes.Text = life.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to store your data in labels. Labels and textboxes should only be used for user interaction (input and output/display). Store your data in variables, fields or properties. It is even better to use separate classes for your game logic instead of performing the logic inside the form

```
public class Game
{
    private const int InitialLifesCount = 100;

    public Game()
    {
         EnemyLifes = InitialLifesCount;
    }

    public int EnemyLifes { get; set; }

    public AttackEnemy()
    {
        EnemyLifes--;
    }
}
```

In the form you can write

```
private _game = new Game();
```

In the button click:

```
_game.AttackEnemy();
lblTotalEnemyLifes.Text = _game.EnemyLifes.ToString();
```

It is also a good idea to have a look at [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.90).aspx). If you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your game class and bind the class properties to your labels, then the labels will update automatically.

Besides enhancing clarity, the separation of logic and I/O allows you to write [unit tests](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/create-and-run-unit-tests-vs.aspx) for your game logic. In a unit test you can write

```
[TestMethod]
public void AttackingEnemyReducesHisLifes()
{
    var game = new Game();
    int lifesBefore = game.EnemyLifes;
    game.AttackEnemy();
    Assert.AreEqual(lifesBefore - 1, game.EnemyLifes);
}
```